# How to save textview when application is closed?

Tags: java, android, textview, sharedpreferences, onsaveinstancestate

I'm trying to save `textview` from `getIntent` String. When I close the application, then open again, `textview` is null. I have used many methods like `onSaveInstance`, `SharedPreference` but all failed.

Code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    jamShubuh = findViewById(R.id.jamShubuhTextView);
    jamDzuhur = findViewById(R.id.jamDzuhurTextView);
    jamAshar = findViewById(R.id.jamAsharTextView);

    getShubuh = getIntent().getStringExtra("getShubuh");
    getDzuhur = getIntent().getStringExtra("getDzuhur");
    getAshar = getIntent().getStringExtra("getAshar");

    jamShubuh.setText(getShubuh);
    jamDzuhur.setText(getDzuhur);
    jamAshar.setText(getAshar);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("shubuh", getShubuh);
    editor.putString("dzuhur", getDzuhur);
    editor.putString("ashar", getAshar);

    retriveData();

private void retriveData() {
    SharedPreferences getData = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    getData.getString("shubuh", null);
    getData.getString("dzuhur", null);
    getData.getString("ashar", null);
}
```

Comment: This is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you show some random code that does not show the declaration of R. In other words, you are using a variable that you don't show called R, which could be causing said error. Also, can you include an error message, with pointers to the line you describe causes the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your attempt with `SharedPreferences`. That would seem to be an appropriate option for persisting just three `String`s.

Comment: @KnowNoTrend `R` is an auto-generated resource class in Android. It's just a bunch of `final static` fields. It's normally unnecessary to include it in questions.

Comment: @MikeM. wait ya

Comment: @MikeM. Question is editted

Answer (score 1):

To use the shared preferences, I suggest you to make certain class to handle it. Maybe like this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class MyPrefManager {
    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public void setPref(Context context, String key, String value){
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getPref(Context context, String key){
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        value = null;
        String X = sp.getString(key, value);
        return X;
    }

}
```

Then use setPref method to set the value and getPref method to get the value. Assume now you are in MainActivity and you want to save values of getShubuh, getDzuhur, and getAshar to Preference Manager, you can do something like this :

```
MyPrefManager MPM = new MyPrefManager();

MPM.setPref(MainActivity.this,"keyShubuh",getShubuh);
MPM.setPref(MainActivity.this,"keyDzuhur",getDzuhur);
MPM.setPref(MainActivity.this,"keyAshar",getAshar);
```

And to get the value of keyShubuh, keyDzuhur, and keyAshar wherever you want, you can do something like this.

```
MyPrefManager MPM = new MyPrefManager();

MPM.getPref(AnyActivity.this,"keyShubuh");
MPM.getPref(AnyActivity.this,"keyDzuhur");
MPM.getPref(AnyActivity.this,"keyAshar");
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Dari Indonesia ya? Saya mau textview.setText(); di save tanpa mencet tombol apapun karena value yang saya dapet hasil dari getIntent().getStringExtra(); dan saya tidak mau ada tombol sama sekali di xml nya. Masalahnya ketika saya tutup aplikasinya trus saya buka lagi, value yang ada di textview berubah jadi null.

Comment: Iya mas, simpan saja dulu di shared preferences, lalu load valuenya setiap awal load projectnya. Kalo pengen ga ada tombol, berarti buat addTextChangedListener pada EditText nya. Nanti akan muncul 3 method, gunakan method onTextChanged untuk set value nya.

Answer (score 0):

To save text state

```
//Saving The Text Entered by User
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);// getting the reference of editext from xml
    CharSequence text = editText.getText();// getting text u entered in edittext
    outState.putCharSequence("savedText", text);// saved that text in bundle object i.e. outState
}
```

and restore saved text

```
//Restoring the State
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);// getting the reference of textview from xml

    CharSequence savedText =
            savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedText");// getting the text of editext

    editText.setText(savedText);// set the text that is retrieved from bundle object
}
```

instead of EditText you can use TextView.